# making a $http request in ng-boilerplate

Tags: angularjs, http, ngboilerplate

My supervisor wants me to make a demo using ng-boilerplate.  The docs note that it makes use of

```
file:///path/to/ng-boilerplate/build/index.html
```

as opposed to using $http.  I created a simple JSON file for some mock data.  I want to access the data.  Right now I am trying to get it in a controller.  When I get this to work I will move the request to a service.

Here is my initial request:

```
$http.get('src/documents/itineraryList.json').then(function(data) {
   console.log(data)'
}
```

This method does not work because I do not cannot make a $http request.  The link in my console gives me access to the json file.

So I refactored my code

```
$http.get('http://src/documents/itineraryList.json').then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

However, itineraryList.json comes up red in my Networks tab in dev tools.  I shortened and added to my path as much as I possibly could.  However, I am not able to access the json file.

Is there a better approach? This is a common boilerplate.  I could not find a fix on stack overflow.

Comment: Are you using a webserver? some features need a webserver to work. you can create a simple webserver with node.js `http-server -p 8080` or with python `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

Comment: basically can't use ajax in `file://` protocol

Comment: I was using $grunt watch.  I figured there wasn't a quick fix.  I am curious if I can create a server file in the root and server the build files as static.  I am going to try this.  If it works I will certainly add the answer.